# Проблема с кодировкой .min файлов при переносе на хостинг в filezila

Tags: javascript, jquery, файлы, filezilla

Столкнулся со следующей ситуацией: при переносе .min файлов например bootstrap.min.js на хостинг через filezilla сбивается кодировка. С самим файлом проблем никаких и код корректный.А вот после того как файл на уже залит на хостинг вылезают некорректные символы. Подскажите в чем причина? Ниже скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из-за данной проблемы перестает отрабатывать код и приходится перезаливать((

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение проблемы.Нужно выставить бинарный режим при передаче файлов.